# Can't connect to SQL when running from UNC path

Tags: c#, sql-server

Works fine when running locally. But not when running from UNC path (still running on the same physical machine). Also works fine with other SQL servers... just this one (it's a named instance/different port, but i've tried connecting using ip,port; hostname\instance; hostname\instance,port; hostname,port and various derivations of connection string, still no joy;

```
<add key="onnString" value="Data Source=10.121.45.201,14332;Initial Catalog=FACEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>

string comm = "SELECT * FROM PAYMENTS WHERE CODE = '" + org_code + "'";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["onnString"]);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm, conn);
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120;
        short retries = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
```

Error;

```
Message "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An invalid argument was supplied.)"   string
```

Any bright ideas?

The account definitely has access (i can connect via ssms)

Comment: Just a note, doing `WHERE CODE = '" + org_code + "'";` is really bad. You should be using a parameter to pass in that data. See [DataAdapter Paramters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_1) on the MSDN

Comment: Did you check out the related questions in the column to the right of this question? That's a very common error message that has been discussed extensively. Are you really using port 14332? The default is 1433 (I suppose you did change the port if you specified it, but something to check).

Comment: To Scott's point, https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom

Comment: Try browsing for instance of database using SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) which comes with SQL server.  On the login window use pull-down for Server : Select Browse for more : Press plus sign for Database Engine.  All the instance of Server will be shown.  Connect using the instance name.

Comment: ScottChamberlain thanks, but it's an internal app. Eric J yes, nothing seems similar to our issue or of any help. jdweng i'm not quite sure what you're suggesting. I have confirmed I can connect via SSMS.